# Auth0 & Next-Auth Malformed JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, auth0, next-auth

I am attempting to setup authentication in my NextJS project and I am using [Next-Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/). I am currently trying to setup a simple `GET /me` route that would be hit through React Query using the access_token retrieved by a successful Auth0 session Login.

**BUT: the access_token received form Next-Auth w/ Auth0 useSession() is malformed**

EDIT: I think the issue is that next-auth / auth0 is storing the token as an encrypted JWE. I need to figure out how to decrypt this and pass it to my api

- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/243
- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/249
- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/5214

#### FRONTEND

in my `pages > api > auth > [...nextauth].js` I have the following configuration

```
const authOptions = {
    providers: [
      Auth0Provider({
        clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,
        idToken: true,
      }),
    ],

    // Configure callbacks  https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks
    callbacks: {
      // The JWT callback is called any time a token is written to
      jwt: ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
        if (account) {
          token.access_token = account.access_token;
          token.id_token = account.id_token;
          token.auth0_id = token.sub;
          token.type = account.token_type;
        }
        delete token.name;
        delete token.picture;
        delete token.sub;
        return token;
      },

      // The session callback is called before a session object is returned to the client
      session: ({ session, user, token }) => {
        const newSession = {
          user: {
            auth0_id: token.auth0_id,
            email: token.email,
          },
          token: {
            access_token: token.access_token,
            id_token: token.id_token,
            token_type: token.type,
          },
        };
        return newSession;
      },
    },

    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  };

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

##### Auth0 Config

in Auth0 Dashboard: `Auth0 > Applications > Applications > <PROJECT_NAME> > AdvancedSettings > OAuth` the `signature algorithm` is `RS256`

##### Successful Login Landing Page

here I am using `const { data: session, status } = useSession();` to extract the value of the current session (which matches the shape created in the `session callback` of `pages > api > auth > [...nextauth].js` -- and has the `access_token`)

#### _app.jsx component

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

##### API Requests (from the frontend)

for each API request to the server I am setting the headers as such

```
    if (token) headers["authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

##### Server Middleware

I created an `auth` middleware function that serves 2 purposes.

1. Validate the JWT passed to the route ( THIS IS WHERE THINGS BREAK )
2. Attempt to find a user in my postgres DB with matching auth0_id (auth0|)

below is the `auth` middleware

```
// Auth0
import { isPublicRoute } from "../services/auth0/index.js";

import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt";
import jwks from "jwks-rsa";

//  I have copied this directly from the Auth0 Dashboard: Applications > APIs > QuickStart

//  the express-jwt library is failing - error below
const validator = expressjwt({
  secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: "https://dev-ikfyop4g.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json",
  }),
  audience: "thunderbolt",
  issuer: "https://dev-ikfyop4g.us.auth0.com/",
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
});

// NOTE:  we are not actually getting to this function
// This function will retrieve the user and feed it into the request
// into a populated user model, if the id is not in the database it
// will create a new user and pull the base data from auth0
const userInjector = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (isPublicRoute(req)) return next();
  if (!req.auth0?.sub) throw badImplementation("JWT missing in userInjector");
  req.user = await userFromReq(req);
  console.log("THE USER INJECTOR RESULT :: req.user", req.user);
  next();
};

const auth = () => {
  return [validator, userInjector];
};

export default auth;
```

Inside my server I am importing this `auth` middleware function and using like this

```
server.use(auth());
```

## THE `express-jwt` ERROR

```
UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed
    at new UnauthorizedError (/Users/mrt/Documents/MrT/code/M/bolt/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/errors/UnauthorizedError.js:22:28)
    at /Users/mrt/Documents/MrT/code/M/bolt/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/index.js:133:35
    at step (/Users/mrt/Documents/MrT/code/M/bolt/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/mrt/Documents/MrT/code/M/bolt/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/index.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/mrt/Documents/MrT/code/M/bolt/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/index.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The access_token that I am receiving **from Auth0** is malformed. Upon further investigation I would agree. The AccessToken I am receiving (as a JWT) has 5 parts (parts are strings separated by a period `.`.

```
Access Token From Auth0 Session 

eyJhbGc<REMOVED_CHUNK>uYXV0aDAuY29tLyJ9..       // 2 period w/ nothing inbetween??

zOKQ2<REMOVED_CHUNK>rSm6.

9qbS5yndGKkrZ9Tc_dL8ZOuHtp_-e58uGqvGHgcpcFS8-s6SEHJYZ0_g7Ii7aYQe4AdbeK9ekW-704X_6C1r5JH3-9yBz<REMOVED_CHUNK>6Rn3Q8U0YC_x8Vp9pF_EA4GHjevXrh3HFBzCY4AEAx-Rmnzk4tZDgk3oU2rsY1NleMTwpIj0h29KIsukg113uMt5KCWKVnosSI-psaBu<REMOVED_CHUNK>lf0R_y5ClcXF6XY0ezIvuwoSQOmhulMlPsTxzBVGeoIhsooNntgAc4s.

ojmkoO_CO<REMOVED_CHUNK>URg
```

If everything is configured for RS256 why is Next-Auth w/ Auth0 sending me a malformed JWT.

EDIT: a 5 part JWT is a JSON Web Encryption (JWE) token...?